# STRING_TOO_LARGE скопилированного приложения

Tags: android

Простите, вопрос в виде картинки, т.к. форум интерпретирует код
Приложение скомпилировано, установлено и работает

[image: Код в рисунке]

Comment: Уменьшить строку? Сообщение об ошибке как бы намекает...

Comment: Весьма логично... Но не хотелось бы, чтобы не терять смысл текста. А сколько должна быть длина строки максимум, никто не знает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Максимальная длина строки в APK файле приложения может быть Integer.MAX_VALUE, что равно  2^31 - 1 (или приблизительно 2 миллиарда). Чисто как вариант вы можете создать файл txt где будут ваши строки. Вот например [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732252/textview-shows-string-too-large/51732819.) по вашей проблеме.Вот еще вопросы по длине файлов - [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369117/what-is-the-maximum-amount-of-data-that-a-string-can-hold-in-java).
Именно оттуда я почерпнул информацию о которой вы спрашиваете. Надеюсь это вам поможет в решении вашей проблемы. Удачи :)